# Is there is any way to clear the location details which are already captured from an Android device manually?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-2.2-froyo, android-location

I'm developing an android application which deals with capturing location coordinates with GPS.

I'm also getting the last known location details (via `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`);

It works correctly. But I still need to check it. I need to **clear already captured locations** manually then check it again.

**Is there any way to clear the location details which have already been captured from an Android device manually** (like going to the settings menu and doing something).

I'm using an Android device with **sdk>=android2.2**.

All your ideas are welcome.

Comment: As you don't really get control of the GPS chip at a low level, I think you may end up having to power the phone off. Even then, it may have up to date almanac data cached somewhere and get a fix before you are ready to perform your test. Maybe do the test in a cellar somewhere, if you need that location to be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it.

We cannot able to clear the gps captured location .Because it is in device's internal memory.

We cannot controrl over it.

Answer (score 4):

Well please try the following link, it might help:

[Link to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46783266/1400290)

Detail:
I just disabled the GPS then restarted the Android phone & I found that the locationManager.getLastKnownLocation returned NULL for location

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me. But I found this setting in location after turning it off the app got null as last location

[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me. The following steps did though:

1. On your Android device, navigate to "Location > Google Location History" and select your Google account.
2. Click on "Manage Activity". You will be redirected to the Google Maps App.
3. In Google Maps, Click On "Settings"
4. Scroll down to the "Location settings" section and click on "Delete all Location History"
5. Then clear your Application's cache

Answer (score 0):

**Just disable the GPS and enable it again.**
When you disable the GPS you already clear the cache data. See the first point in this docs: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#last-known

Answer (score -2):

you can clear lat and log value using below code so your location details will be cleared.

you need to add Two Method like below in MyLocationManager which will clear you lat and long value when you Activity Class's onPause Method call.

```
public  setMyLatitude(double paramLat) {
       this.myLat=paramLat;
  }

public  setMyLongitude(double paramLong) {
     this.myLon=paramLong;
}
```

Now Call this set Method when your Application is closing ,that means

```
 @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //Call Set Method from Here ,set them to initial Value     
      super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: GooGLE - Im not want to clear via coding .Im need to clear via manually.Like If we disable/enable gps via "settings" menu like that i want to clear the alreay captured location details manually via go to any menu settings.

Answer (score -2):

Just goto settings--->Applications--->Manage Applications ---> Click on your App ---> then Click on Clear Cache and Data....