# Android Fused Location Provider returns cached location?

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

My app has function to detect user location and I have log of the timestamp when I start request location updates

```
LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(100);
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(100);
long startLocationUpdateTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mLocationListener);
```

When I receive the location updates I also log the timestamp of the location fix

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   long locationElapsedTime = location.getElapsedRealtimeNanos();
   // start process location update from here
}
```

Most of the time it works correctly but I saw some logs which show that the `startLocationUpdateTime` is greater than `locationElapsedTime`. I understand that in those cases, the Fused Location Provider returns cached location data which was computed before I request location updates.

Am I wrong? Could somebody please help me to explain why this happens? Is there the setting to force Fused Location Provider always returns new location?

Comment: I hope it'll hepl you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778338/clear-fused-location-providers-location-for-testing

Comment: @ViralPatel Thank you but it doesn't help much